# Setting a link to an <li> instead of just Text

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Navigation hyperlinks only work when mouse is on the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946776/navigation-hyperlinks-only-work-when-mouse-is-on-the-text)

Can you set a link to the whole width of an < li > instead of just where the text is?

This is what I mean, I want the user to be able to click on anywhere on the button and go to the link and not just the text: http://jsfiddle.net/b7S4L/

One of the problems is that I cannot use display: block; because I have a number after the < a > link for example (1)

Comment: Yes. See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946776/navigation-hyperlinks-only-work-when-mouse-is-on-the-text/6946810#comment-8280435

Comment: @Mrchief - thanks looking at it

Comment: `A` elements should not contain `LI` elements - only a list-type element (`OL`, `UL`) may contain `LI`

Comment: @shef, Semantics Nazi hate it, and it may even fail the validation

Comment: Someone is going downvote crazy on this whole question...

Comment: @Shef: The fact that it works is almost an accident. Just because you can do that doesn't mean it's the right or best way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't want the number on the right to be on a seperate line that's
>   the problem, it should be on the right of the Text

I think I understand what you're trying to do here. Though, I'm not sure because your question has been quite confusing..

First, *do* set `display: block` on the `a`. That is the right thing to do here.

Then, move the number *inside* the `a`, and add a `span` inside:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-147">
    <a href="http://test.vps.graenseguiden.dk/newscat/food/" title="Vis alle indl&#230;g i kategorien Food">
        <span>Food</span> (4)
    </a>
</li>
```

Then, some extra CSS is needed. You should merge the new CSS with what you already have - for the demo, I've added it within the HTML pane for simplicity (marked with `<!--new css right here-->`):

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/b7S4L/3/

```
div.gg_newscats li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 16px 0;
    color: #333
}
div.gg_newscats ul li {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0
}
div.gg_newscats li a span {
    color: #cc0014
}
div.gg_newscats li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none
}
div.gg_newscats li a:hover span {
    text-decoration: underline
}
```

The messing around with `span` and `:hover` is to keep the colour and underline exactly as you had it.

Comment: looking at the jfiddle, I think you nailed it, let me try to integrate it

Comment: I am shocked. This could have been achieved with no mark-up changes and using one of your favourite properties! All that was needed was to apply `display:inline-block` to `div.gg_newscats li a` and then to reduce the padding down a bit. ;)

Comment: @tw16: `display: inline-block` is indeed *my favourite*, but I'm not sure how it could have solved this problem :(

Comment: @tw16: That's close, but with that, only [the text is](http://jsfiddle.net/b7S4L/7/) clickable. I wasn't kidding when I said `"Though, I'm not sure because your question has been quite confusing.."`. The hover on the button is a trap!

Comment: Don't fret it is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/b7S4L/6/ :) I was typing out the solution when I saw your answer accepted, so I figured no need to post another answer if OP's problem is solved. *Edit* Actually on testing I realise the styling just looks like a link. Oh well. Never did like `inline-block`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't style the LI at all, (other than float:left and clearing padding, marging and list-style-type) if needed. Put all styling on the A (and use display:block).

Comment: right, that sounds the way to do it

Comment: This *IS* the way to do it. I'm not sure why someone down-voted this. I've been using this technique for years. LI is just a container, there's not reason to style the container, just the link.

Comment: @Diodeus - http://jsfiddle.net/b7S4L/1/ can't use display: block because it pushes my number thing on the right

Comment: Just put text-align:center and use a BR before the number. You can put as much HTML inside there as you need.

Comment: @Diodeus - I don't want the number on the right to be on a seperate line that's the problem, it should be on the right of the Text

Comment: OK, wrap the text and the number in SPANs and add styles. This works, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes just remove any padding from the LI element and push out the padding as needed on the anchor tag

```
<li class="link-wrapper">
  <a href="http://this.com" >Go Here</a>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.link-wrapper{ 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

.link-wrapper a{
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

Comment: `padding: 3px 3px;`? Why not just `padding: 3px;`?

Comment: Good point, switched it ... but was using it so they could adjust the vertical and horizontal.

Comment: @Bobby Borszich - I cannot for two reasons, if I have a large name on a button this doesn't really make sense, and two, I have the number of items I have in that category, for example (1) which is not part of the < a > and if I do this this gets pushed out.

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tags by default are `inline boxes`, which means that they don't fill their parent entirely (they don't take all the space) and they shrink only to fit their content. Thus you should use this CSS to make'em fill the space of `li` element:

```
li a
{
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Also keep in mind that you should remove any padding from the `li` elements and remove margins of `a` elements. This way, border of anchor tags meet borders of `li` tags. For an example, look at links of [Thought Results.](http://www.thoughtresults.com/geolocation-api)

Comment: this is a good solution but it shifts my numbers on the right too, for example: (1) - http://jsfiddle.net/b7S4L/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:block;` to the style and you're all set!

**EDIT**

Eh, didn't see the jsFiddle example. If you remove the top/bottom padding from the `LI`s and put it on the `A`s, plus put the count in a `SPAN` within the `A`s, these rules will achieve the desired result:

```
div.gg_newscats a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.gg_newscats a span {
    color: black;
}
div.gg_newscats ul li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-148">
  <a title="Vis alle indlæg i kategorien Electrical" href="http://test.vps.graenseguiden.dk/newscat/electrical/">
    Electrical
    <br>
    <span>(1)</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Adding display block wont help, look at the style carefully

Comment: @Chris Still gives me problems, look here - http://jsfiddle.net/b7S4L/1/

Comment: In the file http://test.vps.graenseguiden.dk/wp-content/themes/gg/style.css?549298645, there is still padding being applied to the LI elements. As I said - remove all padding from the LI, put the count **inside the `A` tag within a `SPAN`**, and add the rules I supplied above. If you do those things, it will look and work as you desire. If you only implement a small portion of my suggestion, it isn't going to work - no reason to down vote me for it.

Comment: @Chris - I gave you an upvote, and not a downvote. I am working to try to fix the things you said

Comment: Are you using Firebug? Your CSS is a mess, there's a ton of files, the rules are all scattered... it makes it kind of hard to eliminate the padding when you've got it being added from a bunch of different files. Use Firebug to identify which file a given rule is coming from.  As for the downvote, sorry. Someone has carpet bombed this whole question with spurious downvotes.

Comment: @Chris - The problem is I am only working on the code of some one elses, I am only doing minor stuff in this theme. So I don't have full control. As for downvotes, I got downvoted a lot too, had 3 upvotes, now I have 0. I am trying to fix it via jsfiddle since it's much easier to change - http://jsfiddle.net/b7S4L/2/

Comment: Looks like you're almost there - put a `BR` before the span, and if you can add a rule for `div.gg_newscats a:hover span { text-decoration: none; }` - should be set after that. {EDIT} Ah, n/m... someone posted a copy of my answer and it was accepted already.  C'est la vie

Answer (score 1):

One solution I tend to use is to make the `<a />` element within a `<li />` element blocklevel with

`display: block;`

After that removing any padding you specified on the `<li />` element and add it on the `<a />` element instead and you should get the same visual output, but with the entire `<li />` as a link

Answer (score 1):

While you can manage this with jQuery, you can also use simple CSS for most browsers:

```
<style>
ul { width: 200px; background: #ccc; }
li { line-height: 3em; }
a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 5px; }
</style>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: After seeing the jsfiddle link, more tweaking would be needed due to the presentation method. The solution above is to target the specific question that was asked, not based off of the jsfiddle link.  The easiest way to solve this is by coding it in javascript or jQuery, as it is currently being used, and it would allow the text outside of the link to still reside within the link.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit 2

new code... a lot simpler... only thing that didn't go the way I liked was that the text-decoration of the link had to go.

```
.cat-item
{
    padding: 0px;
}

.cat-item a
{
    padding: 13px 0px 13px 0px;
}

.cat-item span
{
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: black;
}

.cat-item a:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I had to change the markup just a little (put the numbers in a span) but other than that it wasn't too much

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZW6uV/1

had to tack on !important because of a conflicting imported style sheet.

#### Edit

Readers Digest version:  Don't put your padding on the `<li>` ... ever.  Put padding on the `<a>` within the `<li>` and then it will fill the empty space and have the same effect but be able to handle the click also.  -snip-

Comment: I would like the numbers to be on the same line with the < a > tags

Comment: @RyanSammut no kidden... D: ah man... well that makes things maybe less hokey... let me edit my post.

Comment: @RyanSammut got it... is that closer to what you wanted?

Comment: @RyanSammut I saw thirtydot had a better solution though :P ah well... next time. Glad your problem was solved. :)

Comment: You still got my upvote :) But I am afraid thirydot came with a solution earlier, and might be 1% better, but thanks loads anyway

Comment: you're quite welcome :) glad if I can be of help in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can do it this way:

```
$("li.cat-item").click(function () {
    $("a", this).click();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You can do it thru css alone.

Comment: You don't need jQuery. You just set the width and height of `a` equal to that of the `li`.

Comment: Useless - display:block; accomplishes the same thing without javascript.

Comment: Why the downvote?! I said that it can be done this way just because he is already using jQuery. As you can see, he already have a lot of jQuery to do things on the page. Its obvious he can do only with CSS, but he is using a generated theme, then maybe he don't want to change CSS.